# Doing an almost incomplete pivot table operation in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a data frame like the following:

```
values = random.sample(range(1, 101), 15)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 'n': [100, 100, 100, 'reference',  'reference',  'reference', 500, 500, 500, 100, 100, 100,  'reference',  'reference',  'reference'], 'value': values})
```

The values labeled as 'reference' in the `n` column are reference values, which I will eventually plot against. To help with this, I need to make a data frame that has the reference values in a different column, so `columns = ['x', 'n', 'value', 'value_reference']`

Value reference is the reference value for all values of `n` as long as `x` is the same. Therefore, I want to make a data frame like the following:

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 'n': [100, 100, 100, 500, 500, 500, 100, 100, 100], 'value': [values[i] for i in [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]], 'value_reference':[values[i] for i in [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14]]})
```

I got the result here by hard coding exactly what I want to make a reproducible example. However, I am looking for the correct way of doing this operation.

How can this be done?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be this:

```
df["tick"] = df.groupby(["x", "n"]).cumcount()

numbers = df.loc[df["n"] != "reference"]
ref = df.loc[df["n"] == "reference"]
ref = ref.drop("n", axis=1).rename(columns={"value": "reference"})

out = numbers.merge(ref).drop("tick", axis=1)
out = out.sort_values(["x", "n"])
```

which gives me

```
In [282]: out
Out[282]: 
   x    n  value  reference
0  3  100      6         67
2  3  100      9         29
4  3  100     34         51
1  3  500     42         67
3  3  500     36         29
5  3  500     12         51
6  4  100     74          5
7  4  100     48         37
8  4  100      7         70
```

---

Step by step, first we add a tick column so we know which row of value matches with which row of reference:

```
In [290]: df
Out[290]: 
    x          n  value  tick
0   3        100      6     0
1   3        100      9     1
2   3        100     34     2
3   3  reference     67     0
4   3  reference     29     1
5   3  reference     51     2
6   3        500     42     0
7   3        500     36     1
8   3        500     12     2
9   4        100     74     0
10  4        100     48     1
11  4        100      7     2
12  4  reference      5     0
13  4  reference     37     1
14  4  reference     70     2
```

Then we separate out the value and reference parts of the table:

```
In [291]: numbers = df.loc[df["n"] != "reference"]
     ...: ref = df.loc[df["n"] == "reference"]
     ...: ref = ref.drop("n", axis=1).rename(columns={"value": "reference"})
     ...: 
     ...: 

In [292]: numbers
Out[292]: 
    x    n  value  tick
0   3  100      6     0
1   3  100      9     1
2   3  100     34     2
6   3  500     42     0
7   3  500     36     1
8   3  500     12     2
9   4  100     74     0
10  4  100     48     1
11  4  100      7     2

In [293]: ref
Out[293]: 
    x  reference  tick
3   3         67     0
4   3         29     1
5   3         51     2
12  4          5     0
13  4         37     1
14  4         70     2
```

and then we merge, where the merge will align on the shared columns, which are "x" and "tick".  A sort to clean things up and we're done.